# How to connect MySQL database of local server in NetBeans 7.0.1 ( windows)?

Tags: mysql, windows-7, java, database-connection

I am using `NetBeans IDE 7.0.1 on Windows 7` very first time for my php.        Actually in my company there is  a local server ( 192.168.1.99)  where all projects resides and we access phpmyadmin of that local server, Although I have added my project folders with NetBeans (this was also very hectic) but now I am having problem to connect database of my local server as I can see  `192.168.1.99/phpmyadmin` through my browser.
I have set below value

```
Server Host : localhost,
Server port number : 3306,
Administrator username : keshav
Administrator password : ******
```

and when I click on connect, a popup error windows appears with below text

```
Unable to connect to the MySQL server:

org.netbeans.api.db.explorer.DatabaseException:  
org.netbeans.api.db.explorer.DatabaseException: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied  
for user 'keshav'@'localhost' (using password: YES).

The server may not be running or your MySQL connection properties 
may not be set correctly.  Do you want to edit your MySQL connection properties?
```

Answer (score 1):

You turn off the firewall or create rule that allow traffic through 3306 port, or test your connection using command `telnet localhost 3306`. Try instead of `localhost` write `127.0.0.1`.

Answer (score -3):

fisrt you hv to insatll mysql-server and mysql-client in ubuntu. so go in the terminal and write this code. but in the root.. connect your pc to the internet and try this
"apt-get update" then wait for a couple of minutes then write this when the updates completes
"apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client" press Enter and if ask anything then say yes..
it will be install in few minutes. and ask password then enter ur password..
then download mysql query browser and mysql administrative tool from ubuntu software center..after u can use..

Comment: I tried to edit this into something readable but it's such a mess that I gave up. Please use proper words, capitalisation and punctuation. You might also consider using a spell checker.

Comment: I was able to decipher your answer, but really you're just telling them (poorly) how to install MySQL and I don't really see at all how this helps the op.